# What is the difference between post and dispatch in boost::asio?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, threadpool, asio

I am trying to use [boost:asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) library to create a threadpool. The official documentation says :

> dispatch : Request the io_service to invoke the given handler.
>
> post: Request the io_service to invoke the given handler and return immediately.

Could someone explain how these two differ ?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is `dispatch` may run `handler` (the `CompletionHandler` passed to it) inside it which means you will wait for it to finish, if it does, before the function returns.  `post` on the other hand will not run `handler` itself and returns back to the call site immediately.

So, `dispatch` is a potentially blocking call while `post` is a non-blocking call.

Comment: What determines if the"potential" aspect is realized?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz If `dispatch` can grantee that *the handler will only be called in a thread in which the `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` member functions is currently being invoked* then it may make it a blocking call.

Answer (score 2):

`Post` ensures that the thread that calls post will not immediately attempt to process the task.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html

> but without allowing the io_service to call the handler from inside
>   this function.

Dispatch makes no such promise; and may be completed by the time the function returns.

Comment: may or is guarenteed to?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz may.  It only promises that it will be run on a thread that called `run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one()`

Comment: @ChristopherPisz If `dispatch()`ing a job to a strand (or any other single-execution object), that is already busy (i.e. running some other completion handler), then `dispatch()` will behave like `post()` and mark the job for later execution.